# Unable to add an array index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to allocate names for the index in an array while using for loop. how can i achieve this. please guide me.

```
// using in a http response
   for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            this.sf.push({f(i) : // do something)
          };
```

i want to get something like

```
f0: 1,
f1: 5,
f2: 9
```

Comment: we use map `test.map((el, i) =>({[`f${i}`]: el}))`

Comment: An array can have keys for values, try making it an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to transform the array into an object. Here is a sample code:

```js
let test = [1,5,9,10,15,25];
let obj  = {};
for (let i = 0; i<test.length; i++) {
  obj["f" + i] = test[i];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // prints {"f0":1, "f1":5, "f2":9, "f3":10, "f4":15, "f5":25}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to turn the *array*, `[1,5,9,...]`, into an *object*, `{f0: 1, f1: 5, f2:9, ...}`?

If so, you can use `Array.reduce()` for the conversion:

```
const test = [1,5,9,10,15,25]; 

const result = test.reduce((accum, elem, index) => {
  accum[`f${index}`] = elem;
  return accum;

}, {});
```

UPDATE:

Turns out, you can use the same method to keep it as an `Array`:

```
const arrayResult = test.reduce((accum, elem, index) => {
  accum[`f${index}`] = elem;
  return accum;

}, []);

arrayResult; // [f0: 1, f0: 5, ...]
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be a little different from other answers. 
I would prefer using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as this is more clear and explicit.

```js
const sf = {}
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  sf[`f${key}`] = value
}
console.log(sf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** function for that. Such as:

```js
test = [1,5,9,10,15,25];
new_arr = [];
test.map(function(element, index) {new_arr.push('f'+index+':'+element);})
console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         for( const [key, value] of Object.entries(test)){
                let obj= {};
                obj['f' +key] = value;
                this.sf.push(obj);
                    }
```